# Interface USB to micro controller

Tags: microcontroller, usb, ethernet, interface

Following thing I want project.

1. micro controller
2. USB interface
3. Ethernet

Do I require external USB driver to get USB interface with microcontroller?
Is it inbuilt in microcontroller? I am new to this kind of interfacing.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Please refine it with some more details explaining what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of choice in micro-controlers with built-in USB hardware, so if you choose one of those you won't need external USB hardware.

But you will still need

- USB firmware on the micro-controller
- USB driver on the PC

Comment: I KNOW ROM CAN BE CONNECTED VIA I2C LINES TO PROCESSOR, DO V NEED ANY INTERMEDIATE IC?

Comment: STOP SHOUTING! What has I2C ROM got to do with connecting a microcontroller to a computer through USB?!

Comment: @ashish It seems that you're quite confused about what you're trying to do. Take a step back and try to see the big picture. Then update your question with relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on *how* you want to connect to the microcontroller.

If all you want to do is send simple commands and receive data back, then the simplest way of interfacing is through a USB to TTL Serial chip.  Something like an FT232R or MCP2200.  That cuts development time down to a minimum since you don't need to implement a full USB stack in your microcontroller.

However, if you want to control it differently, say have it act as a USB HID device, or an Audio Isochronous pipe, or maybe a USB Ethernet interface, then you will need a microcontroller that has built-in USB.  There us, as Wouter mentioned, a very wide range of microcontrollers with USB built in.  Most (if not all) microcontroller manufacturers do them, so have a browse through your favourite maker's website for them.

Implementing USB in a microcontroller though, from the point of view of software, can be an onerous task.  There will be libraries and/or sample code available for the microcontroller, but often even with that available it can take a lot of time and effort to develop the software you need.